# Manga with a robot with a penis cannon

Tags: gintama

It's about a boy and a girl, and the only scene I remember is one in which they are in a fighting robot, facing off against a bad guy in a robot with a penis cannon. The robot fires a huge shot and an old lady says "quick! After it fires a huge load it needs time to recharge" and someone else says "sadly that's true about most men".

Another line in that same scene: the girl and boy are very cramped in the robot, the boy is rubbing up against the girls back, and she asks "what is that poking me?" He says something like "it's the growing tree of the puberty forest". I don't remember the exact line, it was years ago and it made me laugh.

Comment: Well, the "penis cannon" meme comes from "Sora no Otoshimono" but pretty sure that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: the sexual innuendo kinda sounds like Godannar but there doesn't seem to be a manga of it

Comment: first thing i could think of: Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Cannon where the guy rides a tank with it. But he was alone in it so guess its not it

Comment: Could it possibly be Dead Leaves?

Comment: Just maybe tegen toppa gurren laggan? I remmember some episode about a bathing house were something kinda similar happend.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the [Neo Armstrong Cyclone Jet Armstrong Cannon](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Neo_Armstrong_Cyclone_Jet_Armstrong_Cannon) from [Gintama](http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?id=918).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It could also be the "Kaien" robot from Gintama, here is a picture of it firing from episode 235, and the dirty humor definitely fits the series, although I didn't hear that exact quote in the episode.

[image: Kaien robot firing]

and here is the same scene from the manga
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be[Cannon God Exaxxion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon_God_Exaxxion)

> Hōichi Kano, the Grandson (revealed in stage three to be son) of world famous inventor Hōsuke Kano, is a student at Howa High School in Musashino City, Japan. At the tenth anniversary of first contact with the Leopoldians, an alien race, the unveiling of an Elevator Ship, designed for orbital transport to and from the Leopoldian home world and Earth, is about to take place. However, this was just a ploy to take control of the Earth, using their advanced technology and large Leopoldian work force on Earth to their advantage. It is now up to Hōichi, with the help of his grandfather, his school friend Akane, and Isaka, who recently transferred to Howa High School, to stop them and save Earth.
>   And makes use off allot of obscure jokes like the one mentioned in your question.